# why in Java8 the TreeNode subclass in HashMap extends LinkedHashMap.Entry instead of directly extending HashMap's Node subclass?

Tags: java

Actually a treenode is a node of a red-black tree, and needs a parent field, a left field and a right field to form a tree. but I don't see any necessity for it to have some attributes of an LinkedHashMap.Entry.

Is there anyone who knows the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because the gain from having separate `TreeNode` in `HashMap` and `LinkedTreeNode` in `LinkedHashMap` is marginal?

Or because `LinkedHashMap` needs a `LinkedTreeNode` that would need to extend from to separate classes?

Let's assume that `HashMap` had a `HashMap.TreeNode` class that extends solely from `HashMap.Node`.

`LinkedHashMap` needs a similar class `LinkedHashMap.LinkedTreeNode` that needs to extend from `LinkedHashMap.Entry` (which in turn extends from `HashMap.Node`), but would also need to extend from `HashMap.TreeNode` because of the way the two classes are interwoven.

That would require extending from two classes, which Java explicitly prohibits.

Comment: Thanks a loooooooooooot for answering! I prefer your second explanation :)